# Binary search does not work correctly (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I've implemented binary search in Python, and here's the code:

```
def binary_search(list, target):
    first = 0
    last = len(list) - 1

    while first <= last:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if list[midpoint] == target:
            return midpoint
        elif list[midpoint] < target:
            first = midpoint + 1
        else:
            last = midpoint - 1

    return None
```

And I tried to test it with the following code:

```
l = ["Sam", "John", "Martha", "Garrett", "Julia"]
print(binary_search(l, "Sam"))
```

And it returns `None`, instead of 0. I reread the code a hundred times and could not find the mistake. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: "I reread the code a hundred times" - Read the data instead.

Comment: Binary search like you’re trying to do only works if the list being searched is (already) sorted.

Comment: Reading your code is a good idea, but in some cases you’ll have to debug it: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The Input to Binary Search **should be Sorted**.

Comment: Also don’t call a variable or parameter `list` because that overrides the builtin `list`. I use a convention that list variables are plurals e.g. `names` because then you can iterate it using e.g. `for name in names:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Lautris mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917674/binary-search-does-not-work-correctlypython/68917713#68917713), the input list must be pre-sorted.

So try testing with the following code:

```
l = ["Sam", "John", "Martha", "Garrett", "Julia"]
l.sort()
print(binary_search(l, "Sam"))
```

Or:

```
l = ["Sam", "John", "Martha", "Garrett", "Julia"]
print(binary_search(sorted(l), "Sam"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Binary search requires the input list to be pre-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It works *perfectly*.

```py
def binarySearch(arr, target):
    first_index = 0
    length = len(arr)
    while (first_index <= length):
        mid_point = first_index + ((length - first_index) // 2)

        res = (target == arr[mid_point])

        # Check if x is present at mid
        if (res == 0):
            return mid_point - 1

        # If x greater, ignore left half
        if (res > 0):
            first_index = mid_point + 1

        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        else:
            length = mid_point - 1

    return None

if (result == None):
    print("Element not present")
else:
    print("Element found at index", result)
```